# Fields missing from 'Available Fields' list when creating list view

Tags: permissions, fields, list-view

We have users who are trying to create a custom list view of accounts, but some of the fields they require in the view are missing from the list of available field. They are able to see the fields and edit them when viewing the account object directly.

Any idea what I need to do to make fields available for list views?

Reply to comments:

The fields are standard date fields that were added recently, they are nothing special. The fields are already on the page layout, and I can see them when I go to create a list view (I'm admin) but my users can't. I'm creating a new view via the 'Create New View' button on the top level 'Accounts' screen.

Comment: What types of fields are they? Are they MD relationship fields? Also, just checking but is the Account VIEW page a VF page or standard detail page

Comment: adding to @Eric - "You can display only the fields that are available in your page layout" per the doc

Comment: @crop1645 - I thought so to but I tested it and fields that were not on the page layout were still available for display in the list view.....I wonder if it changed or if it was because I was an admin.....Are you seeing the behavior in the doc when you test it?

Comment: @eric : I eat my words -- you are right - even if field is not on page layout and running user isn't sysad, fields will display in list view. I'd swear it didn't use to be this way. Doc may be in error

Comment: @crop1645 - It could be a bug, it could be a new feature and doc not updated, it could be an "enhancement" who knows. One thing for sure, I will not be opening a case for it. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem was that the user was being an idiot and trying to create a list view including fields from Accounts, but creating it from the Opportunities screen...